# How do I find out right data design and right tools/database/query for below requirement

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, cassandra, nosql, bigdata

I have a kind of requirement but not able to figure out how can I solve it. I have datasets in below format

```
id, atime, grade
123, time1, A
241, time2, B
123, time3, C
```

or if I put in list format:

```
[[123,time1,A],[124,timeb,C],[123,timec,C],[143,timed,D],[423,timee,P].......]
```

Now my use-case is to perform comparison, aggregation and queries over multiple row like

1. time difference between last 2 rows where id=123
2. time difference between last 2 rows where id=123&GradeA
3. Time difference between first, 3rd, 5th and latest one
4. all data (or last 10 records for particular id) should be easily accessible.

Also need to further do compute. **What format should I chose for dataset
and what database/tools should I use?**
I don't Relational Database is useful here. I am not able to solve it with Solr/Elastic if you have any ideas, please give a brief.Or any other tool Spark, hadoop, cassandra any heads?
I am trying out things but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choosing the right technology is highly dependent on things related to your SLA. things like how much can your query have latency? what are your query types? is your data categorized as big data or not? Is data updateable? Do we expect late events? Do we need historical data in the future or we can use techniques like rollup? and things like that. To clarify my answer, probably by using window functions you can solve your problems. For example, you can store your data on any of the tools you mentioned and by using the Presto SQL engine you can query and get your desired result. But not all of them are optimal. Furthermore, usually, these kinds of problems can not be solved with a single tool. A set of tools can cover all requirements.

**tl;dr. In the below text we don't find a solution. It introduces a way to think about data modeling and choosing tools.**

Let me take try to model the problem to choose a single tool. I assume your data is not updatable, you need a low latency response time, we don't expect any late event and we face a large volume data stream that must be saved as raw data.

- Based on the first and second requirements, it's crucial to have random access (it seems you wanna query on a particular ID), so solutions like parquet or ORC files are not a good choice.
- Based on the last requirement, data must be partitioned based on the ID. Both the first and second requirements and the last requirement, count on ID as an identifier part and it seems there is nothing like join and global ordering based on other fields like time. So we can choose ID as the partitioner (physical or logical) and `atime` as the cluster part; For each ID, events are ordered based on the time.
- The third requirement is a bit vague. You wanna result on all data? or for each ID?
- For computing the first three conditions, we need a tool that supports window functions.

Based on the mentioned notes, it seems we should choose a tool that has good support for random access queries. Tools like Cassandra, Postgres, Druid, MongoDB, and ElasticSearch are things that currently I can remember them. Let's check them:

- Cassandra: It's great on response time on random access queries, can handle a huge amount of data easily, and does not have a single point of failure. But sadly it does not support window functions. Also, you should carefully design your data model and it seems it's not a good tool that we can choose (because of future need for raw data). We can bypass some of these limitations by using Spark alongside Cassandra, but for now, we prefer to avoid adding a new tool to our stack.
- Postgres: It's great on random access queries and indexed columns. It supports window functions. We can shard data (horizontal partitioning) across multiple servers (and by choosing ID as the shard key, we can have data locality on computations). But there is a problem: ID is not unique; so we can not choose ID as the primary key and we face some problems with random access (We can choose the ID and `atime` columns (as a timestamp column) as a compound primary key, but it does not save us).
- Druid: It's a great OLAP tool. Based on the storing manner (segment files) that Druid follows, by choosing the right data model, you can have analytic queries on a huge volume of data in sub-seconds. It does not support window functions, but with rollup and some other functions (like `EARLIEST`), we can answer our questions. But by using rollup, we lose raw data and we need them.
- MongoDB: It supports random access queries and sharding. Also, we can have some type of window function on its computing framework and we can define some sort of pipelines for doing aggregations. It supports capped collections and we can use it to store the last 10 events for each ID if the cardinality of the ID column is not high. It seems this tool can cover all of our requirements.
- ElasticSearch: It's great on random access, maybe the greatest. With some kind of filter aggregations, we can have a type of window function. It can handle a large amount of data with sharding. But its query language is hard. I can imagine we can answer the first and second questions with ES, but for now, I can't make a query in my mind. It takes time to find the right solution with it.

So it seems MongoDB and ElasticSearch can answer our requirements, but there is a lot of 'if's on the way. I think we can't find a straightforward solution with a single tool. Maybe we should choose multiple tools and use techniques like duplicating data to find an optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborated response. I have a visibility that I will need more than one tool. so checking out some of the mentioned by you. Currently we have Elasticsearch for random query and Aggregation. I will try to implement the window function.

Comment: Few questions. A little insight will be helpful. 
1. Will Spark alongside Cassandra be helpful?
2. Any Efficient Ways to  data duplication?
Really Appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. Certainly is helpful, but it depends on your usage. Cassandra is a column-family database. You have a partition key and based on the partition key you can query efficiently. On another side, if your query causes a full scan, it checks all partitions for a result and it's not efficient as other DBs that support optimization like filter push down. 2. For a big-data environment, I prefer put data on a Kafka and then consume and insert them into different storage. Using tools like Apache Nifi can help in these situations.

Comment: Thanks @meysam Appreciate your feedback. I will look through the mentioned tools and will try to find the solution.

Comment: Your question is too vague and it would help if you provided a real life example to show what you're trying to achieve. Without context, you are likely to get opinion-based responses than objective answers.